# Can't read JSON array value with a "$" in the array name,

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a JSON-encoded array, but in one of the array values is a "$" in the array name.
When I will read the value with the follow code below, didn't get I an value.

```
<?php
error_reporting("E_ERROR");
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Amsterdam"); 
$json = file_get_contents('http://jotihunt.net/api/1.0/nieuws');
$json = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($json as $key1 => $item) {
    foreach ($item as $key2 => $value) {

        $id = $item['$id'];

         echo gmdate("d-m-Y H:i", strtotime('+2 hours', $value['datum'])) . '&nbsp;' . $value['titel'] . ' met ID: '.$id.'<br/>';
    }
}
?>
```

Below the JSON array from `$item`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => Array
                (
                    [$id] => 52532555a08789e17900000d /* Can't read this with $item[$id] because the "$" before "id" */
                )

            [titel] => API 1.0    /* $value['titel'] */
            [datum] => 1381180320 /* $value['datum'] */
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => Array
                (
                    [$id] => 524b16eaa08789806a000010
                )

            [titel] => Inschrijving gesloten
            [datum] => 1380652260
        )
```

Does anyone know how I can read `$id`?

Answer (score 3):

The $id item is contained in an ID item. Try:

```
$id = $item['ID']['$id'];
```

Edit: I am not sure why you have the nested loops.
This should be enough:

```
foreach ($json as $key1 => $item) {
 $id = $item['ID']['$id'];
 echo gmdate("d-m-Y H:i", strtotime('+2 hours', $item['datum'])) . '&nbsp;' . $item['titel'] . ' met ID: '.$id.'<br/>';
}
```

Comment: The suggested code uses `$item['$id']` instead of `$item['ID']['$id']` (i.e. it's inconsistent with "the answer").

Comment: Both solutions doens't work.
With $id = $item['ID']['$id'], there is no output from $id

With one loop doens't nothing work.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$item['ID']['$id']`. If you find yourself using `$item[ID]`, you use undefined constant `ID`.

Here is code that works:

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://jotihunt.net/api/1.0/nieuws');
$json = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($json['data'] as $key1 => $item) {
  $id = $item['ID']['$id'];
  echo gmdate("d-m-Y H:i", strtotime('+2 hours', $item['datum'])) . '&nbsp;' . $item['titel'] . ' met ID: '.$id.  '<br />';
}
```

Comment: Both doesn't work. No result :(
Below a link to the live script: [link]http://hq.b10-ict.nl/jotihunt/nieuws.php

En the source code [link]http://hq.b10-ict.nl/jotihunt/nieuws.phps

Comment: You have nested foreach, which is wrong. becquerel's code is close in that it removed the nested foreach, but it needs to use `$id = $item['ID']['$id'];`

Comment: I'm affraid that i don't understand what you did mean.
I have now above code with one forech.

But than there no output from $item['datum'],titel and $id. 
See also the above link to the script aggain.

Comment: Almost there. Replace `$key1['datum']` with `$item['datum']`

Comment: My bad, i was experiment with variables. Both vars don't give a about

Comment: You gave us wrong structure of the json data. I'll update my answer.